# Cannot pass JSON data to JSON.parse() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript throws an error when using JSON.parse(). When I pass it this json data:

```json
{
    "AXzgeQ7vXOjWnFrgjHiM": {
        "0-17-13955610754117-8-2021": {
            "channelId": "17", 
            "end": "1642091400000", 
            "id": "0-17-13955610754117-8-2021", 
            "start": "1642090860000", 
            "title": "Yle Uutiset Alueeltasi", 
            "type": "broadcast"
        }
    }
}
```

Which is imported like: `import stubReminders from './stub_data.json';`

It throws the error:

> Argument of type '{ AXzgeQ7vXOjWnFrgjHiM: { "0-17-13955610754117-8-2021": { channelId: string; end: string; id: string; start: string; title: string; type: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

What should I change to successfully use `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing your imported `stubReminders` as is without trying to parse it. I have tested out an example, and the import parses the JSON automatically.

I hope this works.

Also checkout this codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-feather-tsyfz?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea it was automatically parsed on import!

Answer (score 2):

The `JSON.parse` function takes a [string as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). You are trying to pass an object to it. So you have to convert it to a string before, if you want to use `JSON.parse`.

But keep in mind, that the imported object already is an object, so I think there is no need to parse it.

```
const obj = {
    "AXzgeQ7vXOjWnFrgjHiM": {
        "0-17-13955610754117-8-2021": {
            "channelId": "17", 
            "end": "1642091400000", 
            "id": "0-17-13955610754117-8-2021", 
            "start": "1642090860000", 
            "title": "Yle Uutiset Alueeltasi", 
            "type": "broadcast"
        }
    }
}



console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))
```